marekting cloud - can we automate to send all subscriber data to my subcriber list in marketing cloud in order to automation subs-unsub..helpplssss
I have a scenarion where I am not using connector first of all and I am sending my salescloud data account/contact to marekting cloud data extension through rest api.
Now the tricky part is we have 2 types of customer in sales cloud... fully subscribed(who should get all communication operational and campaigning), only contacts(who should get only operational communications).
I handled this by creating a boolean field in data extension MC_contacts, yes means fully subscribed) and false means partially subscribed and these values I am sending as a rest api request.
and after receiving the data I am copying my MC_contacts=True to new data extension, this part is sorted all campaigning communication will go by using this DE.
But in my first DE where MC_contacts=true and false both are there, I want false contact(operational contact) to make unsubscribed on system level and want to make it subscribe before sending the operational mail and once mail are send then want to make it again unsubscribe ... how I can achieve this through automation ... please help on this because I am stuck sing a long..

Firstly - why do you use REST API and not the standard connector between SC and MC?

Why do you want to do this, is it to avoid sending commercial communications to the operational contacts?
I think you could achieve this by ensuring the first DE (where you have both types of contacts) is non-sendable, so no user can use it by mistake.
I don't think you are supposed to change the status of the customer before and after every send, as it could have other unexpected problems (for instance, you might be overwriting other statuses like held, which could affect your IP reputation).

Thank for you answer
